# Solving minimum bipartite matching with missing edges using Hungarian algorithm

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, assignment-problem

I am interested in a minimum bipartite matching problem, where some edges are missing (i.e., not valid). An intuitive way to solve the problem is to add very large costs for these missing edges and then they can be treated as valid edges so the Hungarian algorithm can be used. However, if the original graph is sparse (or have massive missing edges), adding edges may increase computational complexity. So, I am wondering if there is a better way to deal with the missing edges to keep the sparse structure of the graph when using the Hungarian algorithm.

Though I am not sure, maybe some data structure modification for the Hungarian algorithm can be helpful?

Comment: Yes, there are sparse versions of the Hungarian algorithm. Google will find (some of) them easily.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I tried to search "sparse Hungarian algorithm", but did not find a helpful implementation or reference for the Hungarian algorithm. If you have, could you please provide any?

Comment: Hungarian type of of algorithms: [Cui et al. 2016](https://www.atlantis-press.com/article/25854748.pdf), [Carpaneto,Toth,1983](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02247938), [Carpaneto,Toth,1987](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X87900163), [Hungarian.jl](https://github.com/Gnimuc/Hungarian.jl), [faq](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~brd/Teaching/Bio/asmb/current/Handouts/munkres.html),  related algorithm: [Jonker,Volgenant,1986](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02278710)